# Why does Scala sbt update every time I start it from command prompt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am a beginner in Scala and every time I start sbt from command prompt it goes into a long update and it takes several minutes for the sbt to update. I read in the instructions that the sbt was going to update the first time it was started from the command prompt but in my case it is updating every time I start it.
I have to wait several minutes for it to update and it takes away some of the joy of learning Scala.
So my question is how do I stop sbt from updating every time and is it normal for it to do so?

edit:

This is how my sbt command looks and after this it goes into a long update.

[image]

edit2:

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information: SO, if you call it every time from the same directory and if you can post the output of the command!

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio Edited my question, hope this information is useful.

Comment: I'll assume you haven't changed any settings, so I'm guessing your ivy cache is being erased, or not kept for some reason. Is there anything unusual about your computing environment? Internet cafe? Using different computers?

Comment: @RobinGreen No I am using Scala on my laptop, I installed Scala, sbt and Scala-IDE and haven't changed anything since. But I am a complete beginner in Scala so maybe I changed something unknowingly.

Comment: @HaseebRamish Please exit from sbt and type "dir c:\users\hasseb\.ivy2\cache" at the command prompt. There should be some directories in there.

Comment: @RobinGreen Please check edit 2.

Comment: Well, org.scala-lang seems there... could you please check the content of that directory and see if there is the scala-library.jar?

Comment: Is the system date and time on your laptop correct?

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio Yes there are scala-library-2.10.1 and scala-library-2.9.2 .jar files.

Comment: @RobinGreen Yes the time and date are exactly as they should be.

Comment: mmm but yet it's trying to download the scala-compiler, is that jar with the others, rigth?!

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio I am sorry I didn't understand the question. Is the jar with the which others?

Comment: Sorry bad speaking: please check if also the scala-compiler.jar is in that directory

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio Yes the compiler version of the above mentioned jar files are in that folder as well.

Comment: Well sorry I pass, I think you should file a bug report at this point!

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio Ok, thank you for giving it your time and effort.

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio I have a noob question :), if you have time plz help me: I have installed scala through scala-2.10.2.msi, do I still need scala-sbt? Because I can start scala from console now without it updating itself.

Comment: If you intend the console you launch with the "scala" command it's different from the sbt-console although similar. Sbt is a build tool fo Scala like Maven is for Java, but it's not mandatory, indeed I've always used Maven plugins, for example the one for Eclipse.

Comment: SBt should only update *once*.   Are you deleting the ~/.sbt directory  by accident?  This is the only reason I can think of why it would continually re-resolve scala....

Comment: @Haseeb -- in response to what @jsuereth said ... is your `c:\users\haseeb\.sbt` there when you exit from the console? There should be a `boot` subdirectory, and under that a `scala-2.10.1` directory.

Answer (score 4):

SBT is designed to be started once when you start working on the project and not shut down. This saves you the time it takes for the JVM to start as well as any start up tasks that SBT dose at start up.

So instead of running:

```
sbt test
```

at your operating systems shell prompt you can run

```
sbt
```

With no arguments which will drop you into the sbt prompt.

From hear you can run sbt commands (the same as you normally do but without the sbt prefix because your already in sbt (eg compile, test ....) one after the other with no start up time which is much quicker.

Another big time saver is that in the sbt prompt you can put a ~ at the start of many sbt commands to have them run automatically. eg

~test

Will start running your tests as soon as you save in your IDE/editor.

Comment: Even though this is true, I still do not understand why the lib files are checked/downloaded on each start when they are cached locally. Does anyone know how to suppress this behavior?

Comment: Your answer doesn't hit the question. First question was "why does it update on start?", the second was "how do you stop it?"