# Is every Scala project targeted at a particular sbt version?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I am trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174734/why-does-scala-sbt-update-every-time-i-start-it-from-command-prompt) problem that I am facing. I have sbt version 0.12.2 installed on my laptop but every time I go to my scala assignment folder and start sbt from command prompt it automatically tries to download sbt 0.12.1. I gathered from the

> build.sbt

file that the project is targeted at scala version 2.10.1 but I couldn't find anything on the sbt version.
My question is: **Is there such a thing as sbt target version? If there is how and where can I modify it?**

Note: I can provide the build.sbt file if it helps in solving this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the version of SBT used by a project is specified in a properties file.

Try looking in project/build.properties.

See the "Getting Started" guide [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html#setting-the-sbt-version).

Comment: I can't believe I asked such a noob question :). Thank you I found the sbt version though changing it didn't help with the original problem :(